# Imai - Takai duality for reduced crossed products?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, duality-theorems

I'm currently looking for a citation to a statement of Imai-Takai duality, specifically for reduced $C^{*}$-algebra crossed products, and I can't seem to find one.

It's clear to me that such a result does hold, but I'm trying to find a source to cite that explicitly states this duality theorem in the context of a reduced crossed product.

Comment: Did you check the book "Crossed products" by Williams? Did you check Takesaki's second volume, or any other encyclopedic reference?

Comment: @J.DeRo After some digging, I found it in the appendix of "A Categorical Approach to Imprimitivity Theorems for C*-Dynamical Systems".

Answer (score 0):

I found a reference.  For anyone else who may ever need it, it's in "A Categorical Approach to Imprimitivity Theorems for C*-Dynamical Systems", theorem A.68 in the appendix.